# When PageUp/PageDown a Datagrid - how does the ICollectionView work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a difficult task to solve. When using WPF Datagrid the Paging works fine as long as you don't have any groupings.

However as soon as groupings come into the place, it becomes a bit tricky.  In fact The pageup/down don't work correctly anymore.

One workaround I have found is to access the internal scroll viewer that is wrapper inside the dataGrid by using this:

**helper class:**

```
public static class VisualTreeUtilities
    {
        public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default(T);
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return child;
        } 
}
```

**Actual code:
ctor:**

```
_scrollViewer2 = VisualTreeUtilities.GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(this.dataGrid);


private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {
                case Key.PageUp:
                    _scrollViewer2.PageUp();
                    e.Handled = true;
                    break;
             }
         }
```

This way I can perfectly scroll fine despite using the groupings. The only problem that remains is that Datagrid doesn't take the actual selectedItem with it downwards when paging down, or upwards when paging up.  The selected cell remains at the former position and out of sight when paging away. I wished it was like excel when the selected cell remains there. It means when the second cell of third row is selected and you page down, still the second cell of the third row would be selected.  How could I do something like this in a WPF datagrid?

I need to understand how internally it works. How does the ListCollectionView know how many rows to page down? if I knew how it counts down the rows, I could use the same principle to count down the rows and set the selectedItem to that position and do a cell.focus() and problem solved.

Can anybody help me with understanding the missing bit?

Many Thanks,